# Find few adjacent identical numbers

Tags: ruby, regex, match

Could you help me?
I need a regex that splits strings like

```
"11231114"
```

to

```
['11', '2', '3', '111', '4']
```

Comment: show your attempts. Which lang are you running?

Comment: '11231'.scan(/1+/)
This is ruby. This expression matches only "1". I need all [1-9]. So I need to  match few identical adjacent characters.

Comment: which lang are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) as follows:

```
"11231114".scan(/((\d)\2*)/).map(&:first) 
#=> ["11", "2", "3", "111", "4"]
```

<strike>You could pass a block to [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) pushing the match group to an array.</strike>

```
matches = []
"11231114".scan(/((\d)\2*)/) do |n,r| matches << n end
```

Comment: `"11231114".scan(/((\d)\2*)/).map &:first` looks significally easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can do:

```
var m = "11231114".match(/(\d)\1*/g)
//=> ["11", "2", "3", "111", "4"]
```

You can use similar approach in whatever language/tool you're using.

Approach is to capture a digit using `(\d)` and then match all the back-references for the same using `\1*`.

Comment: In case OP is using Ruby, as hinted at by his comment: `"11231114".scan(/(\d)\1*/).map(&:first)`

Comment: i think op is running ruby.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work in ruby. It gives me that
  => ["1", "2", "3", "1", "4"]

Comment: @IgorBabkin: [It seems to be working here on ruby regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/TWpOev4X48)

Comment: @IgorBabkin see my answer `^^^`

Comment: Ah yeah, I misspoke - the first group is just the digit. `"11231114".scan(/((\d)\2*)/).map(&:first)` should work, as long as you are on a newer Ruby. If you are on an ancient one, hwnd's answer based on the same regexp will still work.

Comment: @IgorBabkin: Did you check my ruby demo link which is working fine using exact same approach shown in my answer.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, there are many things wrong with this answer. 1. The OP clearly requested ruby solution while you provided javascript one. 2. There is no ability in ruby to use `match` to find all the matches (no `//g` modifier at all.)

Comment: @mudasobwa: Just look at the timestamp of my answer and Edit timestamp of OP to add `Ruby` tag. Also check my Ruby regex demo.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this,

```
> str = "11231114"
=> "11231114"
> str1 = str.gsub(/(?<=(\d))(?!\1)/, "*")
=> "11*2*3*111*4*"
> str1.split('*')
=> ["11", "2", "3", "111", "4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) in Ruby 2.2:

```
"11231114".chars.slice_when { |x, y| x != y }.map(&:join)
```

Comment: @mudasobwa Why should someone benchmark answers? Did op ask for quickest way or maybe it is newly introduced restriction on SO? This is just another approach which works great. And by the way it is < 2 times slower(0.000065 vs 0.000039).

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov  I never said that one _should_ benchmark answers. I think that when one suggests to start with splitting string (that might be enormously long) by chars (what appears to be unicode-unfriendly), one should take into account that the wrong advise is worse that an absent advise. At least the benchmark against significantly long input should be performed, unless the only reason to post an answer is to gain rep points.